# Swift - Code=257 "The file “...” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, phasset

I try to read a photo from gallery but it gives this error. When I try with **Simulator** I can get this photo properly but with **personal phone** not. I guess it is about **Sandbox** but i didnt find any solution. **It's not about any permission.**

Note: This image comes from a service and I stored in photo gallery and keep this path in core data . Then I try to read from this url.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask permission to use photo gallery.
Go to **Info.plist** and add the **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description**

And you need to check this permission:

```
func checkPermission() {
    let authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video)
    switch authStatus {
    case .authorized:
        self.displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: YOUR_BUTTON_HERE)
    case .denied:
        alertPromptToAllowCameraAccessViaSetting()
    default:
        break
    }
}

func checkLibrary() {
        let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        if photos == .authorized {
            switch photos {
            case .authorized:
                self.displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: YOUR_BUTTON_HERE)
            case .denied:
                alertPromptToAllowCameraAccessViaSetting()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

func alertPromptToAllowCameraAccessViaSetting() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You are not allow accsess to camera and library", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .cancel) { (alert) -> Void in
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        })

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: All permission is given!

Comment: self.displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: self.changeAvatar) where is it ?

Comment: When user press this button, this method check the permission

Answer (score -1):

```
Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
```

also add the above permission in your Info.plist